# MySQL drop large table without slowdown the service

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I had one table that I want drop. That table use something around 130GB. When I start drop/truncate that table, mysql server slowdown and I get a lot of issues about users using that service.

How can I drop a large table without affect mysql performance?

I already tried create a new table like that I want to drop, rename them and drop unused table (old table), but rename command hangs my mysql service.

I am using:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.28-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: "When I start drop/truncate" - drop or truncate? It's not the same.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I want to clean that table, so both will work. I have no foreign keys and triggers. Truncate can solve that, but hangs mysql service too.

Answer (score 1):

The OS is probably the problem.  Some OSs take a long time to finish deleting a very large file.  Sorry, but you simply have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

When you DROP or TRUNCATE a table in MySQL or MariaDB and you have large buffer pool, there can be server lockup or stall of multiple seconds.The is because when a table is dropped, MySQL will perform a full scan of buffer pool looking for pages that belong to dropped table. This will lock the buffer-pool and you have to wait until it's unlock. If your buffer pool is smaller this will not effect much but if you have larger one, it becomes devastating.

One possible solution can be delete all rows before dropping a table, this will not cause a memory stall because there will be no data in memory.

Another solution can be use of non-InnoDB storage engine for temporary tables. You can specify ENGINE=MyISAM in your **CREATE TABLE** statement. If you have a large code base and don’t explicitly specify the storage engine, you can change the default storage engine to MyISAM by adjusting the following configuration option:

> default_tmp_storage_engine = MyISAM

Of course there are some drawbacks with these solutions. You can find complete details of this bug, solution and drawbacks  [MySQL troubleshooting article](https://shatteredsilicon.net/blog/2021/11/27/mysql-drop-truncate-lock-bug/).

The good news is that the fix itself has been implemented MySQL 8.0.23 and later.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to empty out a large table is to create a new one with the same columns. Truncate will be a lot slower than just dropping

1. Disable foreign key checks
   `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`
2. Rename old table to be dropped
   `RENAME TABLE old TO temp;`
3. Create the new empty table exactly like the older table
   `CREATE TABLE new LIKE old;`
4. Drop old table
   `DROP TABLE temp`
5. Enable foreign key checks 
   `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`

Comment: Step 3 can be `CREATE TABLE new LIKE old;`

Comment: Learned something new !